# Why is my server always returns Last Modified as my current time?

Tags: php, apache, caching, codeigniter

So set my vhost.conf file to have this Expires:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 hours"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/bmp "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 10 years"
```

I think it is working since the Response Headers are returning back a Cache-control set to the future:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=315360000
Expires Sun, 04 Apr 2021 12:27:12 GMT
```

But I look at Firefox's Cache tab and it doesn't look pleasing

```
Last Modified   Thu Apr 07 2011 20:27:08 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
Last Fetched    Thu Apr 07 2011 20:27:09 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
Expires      Sun Apr 04 2021 20:27:07 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

Here's what's happening. Everytime I reload my website, the Last Modified header is always set to my current time. I didn't modify the files so why is it returning my current time?

Comment: You didn't set a cache time for .php scripts. Since PHP output is by definition dynamically generated, it's got a last-modified of "now" by default.

Comment: ic, is it better to add caching in php index files?

Comment: BTW, a well-behaved HTTP/1.1 server should not send an Expires header more than one year in the future.

Comment: add cache headers only if the output of the script is relatively constant. If you've got scripts that don't have query parameters and shouldn't be cached, then adding a global cache rule to all php scripts would probably be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's a PHP script, the output of which was generated when you run the script, so the output has never existed before which means that the server couldn't attach a cache header to it.

You'll need to set the last modified time yourself with a `header()` call.

Comment: it is better to attach header to php scripts?

Comment: It's not *better*, but a *necessity* if you want to send the `Last-modified` header.